# The regular expression doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Trying to replace any non alpha-numeric characters with a hyphen. Can't see why it shouldn't be working. It returns the original string unchanged.

```
item.mimetype = "image/png";

var mimetype = item.mimetype.toLowerCase().replace("/[^a-z0-9]/g",'-');
```

Comment: Okay, I see that in javascript a regular expression has it's own syntax. Neat.

Comment: That depends from the other programming language you are used to write programs in. Perl and Ruby use both the `/a/` syntax too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the regex.

As written, Javascript is looking for the *string* `"/[^a-z0-9]/g"`

```
// This works
"image/png".toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g,'-'); 

// And if writing unquoted regular expressions makes you feel icky:
"image/png".toLowerCase().replace(new RegExp("[^a-z0-9]", "g"), '-');

// And if I might do a full rewrite:
"image/png".toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '-');
```

More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 4):

You've put a string instead of a regex. Do this:

```
.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g,'-');
```